# How do I add universal-darwin-15?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

(Mac OS X 10.11.5, El Capitan) `brew cask install` has been failing for lack of ruby 2.0.0 extension universal-darwin-15. The system has universal-darwin-13 and -14.  I've searched the web and tried upgrading brew, cask, and gem, but none of that adds the darwin version. There are no updates waiting in the AppStore. How do I add it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that some part of your system is using the old Apple-provided ruby, and another is using a newer Homebrew installed version. I spent several hours this morning tracking down a problem with xcode and ipatool, and eventually fixed my `universal-darwin-15` problem with some combination of the following:

`brew uninstall ruby
brew install ruby
gem update
sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 (you can also mv to /tmp)
sudo gem update --system`

Some more here: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/7732

Note that if you have permissions problems involving /usr/local, you should not use sudo to fix them. Make sure your userid is in the wheel group and that /usr/local/* is recursively owned by your userid.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved something similar - it was ultimately a permissions issue for me. I copied a different `universal-darwin` folder in that directory, matched it to the number my system said I was missing (`universal-darwin-16` for me) and then I ended up running:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) your-directory-here
```

on `universal-darwin-16`, the Cask and caskroom directories - you may have to look around a little bit to find the **Cask / caskroom** directories on your system (for me they were in different locations.)